# PIVOT table in MS SQl server

Tags: sql-server

I looking for year pivot data with this following query in MS Sql server

```
select month(createdatetime) as month,
       year(createdatetime) as year,
       count(*) as members
from [toneexcel].[dbo].[teUserMemberSIMAcc] 
where year(createdatetime) > '2015' and status = 'AC'
group by month(createdatetime), year(createdatetime) 
order by year(createdatetime), month(createdatetime)
```

please suggest me, TQ

current output is

```
Month| year | members
-----------------------
1   2016    12914
2   2016    13338
3   2016    13633
4   2016    11110
5   2016    9868
6   2016    7088
7   2016    6785
8   2016    8260
9   2016    8386
10  2016    8506
11  2016    7187
12  2016    7976
1   2017    8535
2   2017    12744
3   2017    579
```

Expected output is

```
Month | 2016   | 2017
----------------------
1       12914  | 8535
2       13338    12744
3       13633    579
4       11110
5       9868
6       7088
7       6785
8       8260
9       8386
10      8506
11      7187
12      7976
```

Comment: Please show sample data and your expected output.

Comment: Give some sample data.

Comment: @madhan post the data in the question itself, not the comments. What you posted doesn't help - it's just a single line of numbers. Did you want one row per year, one per month, what? *Update* the question with the relevant information. I'd do it for you but I can't guess what the data is supposed to look like

Comment: @madhan Can you try my answer?

Comment: @jacky Montevirgen,   yes it is helpfull for me, thank you

Comment: @madhan then go upvote my answer!

Answer (score 0):

According to your sample Data and Expected output. You can consider this. Using `PIVOT`

```
 ;with cte as (
select 1 as Month,2016 as Year,12914 as Members union 
select 2 as Month,2016 as Year,13338 as Members union 
select 3 as Month,2016 as Year,13633 as Members union 
select 4 as Month,2016 as Year,11110 as Members union 
select 5 as Month,2016 as Year,9868 as  Members union 
select 6 as Month,2016 as Year,7088 as  Members union 
select 7 as Month,2016 as Year,6785 as  Members union 
select 8 as Month,2016 as Year,8260 as  Members union 
select 9 as Month,2016 as Year,8386 as  Members union 
select 10 as Month,2016 as Year,8506 as Members union 
select 12 as Month,2016 as Year,7187 as Members union 
select 1 as Month,2017 as Year,8535 as  Members union 
select 2 as Month,2017 as Year,12744 as Members union 
select 3 as Month,2017 as Year,579 as   Members  

)
select * from (
 select *
from cte 
)t
pivot (
max (members)
for year in ([2016],[2017])
)
as pvt;
```

Hope this could Help!

Answer (score 0):

```
select [Month], isnull([2016],0) [2016],isnull([2017],0) [2017]
from 
(
  select *
  from #Table1
) src
pivot
(
  max([members])
  for [year] in ( [2016], [2017])
) piv;
```

OR

```
SELECT  MONTH,MAX(CASE WHEN  YEAR=2016 THEN MEMBERS ELSE '' END) [2016],
 MAX(CASE WHEN  YEAR=2017 THEN MEMBERS ELSE '' END) [2017] FROM #Table1
 GROUP BY MONTH
```